# Django model setup on existing Oracle table

Tags: python, django, oracle, django-models

I have a particular situation which I need help clarifying.

I have an existing Oracle table with an auto increment ID as a primary key

I am creating a django model to sync with that table so i can make use of django's ORM methods such as save(), filter() etc.

I read from the django docs the .save() method can perform both a UPDATE and INSERT depending on if the values passed to the primary key results in a True value (i.e. not a None or null).

In my table I have two columns which together will form a composite primary key.

If I specify primary_key = True on the two attributes on the django model, do I need to remove the primary key tag from oracle table?

Also, do i need to specify the unique_together to tell the django model that  they are unique or will it be able to derive the index i created in the django oracle table?

Thanks.

Comment: Django supports legacy databases (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/) but composite primary keys are not fully supported (https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys)

Comment: Thank you @Selcuk! I guess i have to work around that

Comment: _probably_ if the autoincrememnt on the existing table is called `id`, and you set the `unique_together` in your model, it should work ... Setting `primary_key = True` for 2 columns isn't supported though I don't think.